# Youtube API exclude videos with playback has been disabled by video owner

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

When I use youtube api v3 and retrieve some videos from playlist or channel, sometimes I get videos that are:

"video unavailable. playback has been disabled by video owner. watch on youtube"

Is there a way to exclude such videos from query results using api?